# How can I add a padding-bottom to a display: inline element?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am displaying an "h5" html tag inline along with a "p" html tag inline but I need a padding or margin on the bottom of the paragraph so there is a gap in between the next h5 and p tags. How could I go by doing this?

Currently here is an example of what it looks like

```
THIS IS THE h5 - this is the paragraph
THIS IS THE h5 - this is the paragraph
```

And I need it to look like this (without adding a break)

```
THIS IS THE h5 - this is the paragraph

THIS IS THE h5 - this is the paragraph
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having the `h5` and `p` as inline elements you can simply float them to the left and clear left on the `h5`.

This way you can easily set a bottom margin on the `h5` and `p` without issue.

[Here's an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gv6CC/)

**CSS:**

```
h5,p{float:left;margin-bottom:10px;}

h5{clear:left;margin-right:5px;}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a second example using Matthew's idea of using `line-height`.

http://jsfiddle.net/gv6CC/1/

**CSS**

```
h5,p{float:left;line-height:150%;}

h5{clear:left;margin-right:5px;}
```

Comment: Instead of margin you could also use line-height

Comment: +1 But actually floating in this situation might just call for other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `display: inline-block;` on them, that will allow setting margin/padding. The problem with this is Internet Explorer < 7 will not understand `inline-block` on naturally non-inline elements.

You could (if you need old IE support):

- hack around this: [Cross Browser Support for inline-block Styling](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)
- put a `div` around the `h5` and `p` and put the padding on that.

**UPDATE:** [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/3PaHY/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `display: inline;` you could use `line-height: 20px;`

Example:

```
h5, p {
 display: inline;
 line-height: 20px;
}
```

but you should give the `h5` and `p` an ID or class if you won't this would aplly to all `h5` and `p` tags in your Document.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing any CSS, you could also add a `<br />` in between each tag pair:

```
<h5>title</h5><p>this is the paragraph</p>
<br />
<h5>title</h5><p>this is the paragraph</p>
```

**I know** it might not be the purest solution, but it might be the easiest & most cross browser-friendly.  Plus, a `<br />` separating `inline` elements is perfectly acceptable. ;-)